# mysql query for Export CSV file in php

Tags: php, mysql

i write simple Query in php for export data in CSV file but something is wrong with my Query of Syntex Error, can anyone tell me how to solve this? sorry for this liitle question, i m new in PHP.

`$CSVQuery= "SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '/n' ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Query should be as below:

> $CSVQuery= "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED
>   BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '/n' FROM table ";

For more details refer this link : [MySQL Tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

Comment: i execute the Query successfully but now this time its not allowing me to create file in tmp folder, here is the error:

Can't create/write to file '\tmp\member_personal_info2.csv' (Errcode: 2)

can you tell me the solution?

Comment: check for permission of **temp** folder

Comment: i checked andgave the permission to the folder but its showing same error :(

Comment: Ok, then can you try with another path? i think it will solved your issue.

Comment: Thnks, i just changed the path and its solved now ;)

Comment: when you hover near the **up/down** arrow given left side of every answer, you can see **Right** arrow underneath down arrow. just click on it.

Comment: hy there ? my code i working fine in localhost but when i upload it and try to generate the file, it does'nt work, shall i change the file location ? what will be download file location? i want to download in my PC after pressing the generate button...

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quote in your code and use a backslash for the `\n`...

```
$CSVQuery= "SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";
```

Comment: i execute the Query successfully but now this time its not allowing me to create file in tmp folder, here is the error: Can't create/write to file '\tmp\member_personal_info2.csv' (Errcode: 2) can you tell me the solution?